# Importing Google OAuth2Client in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, google-authentication

I'm trying to use an example by Google to verify the id token for my client. Here's the example (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth):

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library'); // <-- here's the error
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //const domain = payload['hd'];
}
verify().catch(console.error)
```

My problem is the first line, where I import the Google Auth library. If I import the library this way, I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) error, since the path is interpreted incorrectly as "localhost/(root)/google-auth-library" (root is the name of the root of the project). On the other hand, if I type in the whole relative path all the way to "src" I'm getting a 'Syntax Error: Unexpected token "<"'.

What would be the right way to import the library?
Note, that this is an Angular 4 project, I already installed the library using npm, but without importing it, I still cannot use OAuth2Client class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, apologies, haven't tested it in angular but works in a node typescript project.

```
import * as gApi from 'google-auth-library';
const gClient = new gApi.OAuth2Client(YOUR_CLIENT_ID);
/*Should wrap in try catch...
  Also needs to be in an async method to use await, otherwise use promise then, error 
syntax
*/
const payload = await gClient.verifyIdToken({ idToken: YOUR_TOKEN, audience: YOUR_CLIENT_ID });
```